# how to show hidden button if more than 1 checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons add and group. Initially group button is hidden. Add button is used for creating records.

So for example:
When 5 records are created(pressing 5 times add button). Now if user selects more than
`checkbox`, then the hidden group button should appear. Can any body please tell me how to do this?

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/176/)

I am using `bootstrap css` and for hiding I do as

```
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary hide" value="Group">
```

**UPDATE**
Check boxes will only appear if user enters some records. Filling the form and after pressing the add button

Comment: There are no checkboxes in your jsfiddle example?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you need to enter some records then only checkbox will appear,enter name,email and number,press add button

Comment: More than (5 ?) checkboxes ?

Comment: @Twocode more than one,

Comment: javabeginner i updted my fiddle check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/179/)

```
$(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
    if($('#mytable input:checkbox:checked').length > 1) {
        $('#btn2').removeClass('hide')
    }
    else {
        $('#btn2').addClass('hide')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a check in the `change` event for the checkboxes. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/178/) and example below:

```
$(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
    if(!this.checked)
    {
        key=$(this).attr('name').replace('mytr','');
        alert(key);
        obj[key]=null;
    }

    //updated using your bootstrap class to show/hide
    if($('#mytable input:checkbox:checked').length > 1) {
        $('#btn2').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#btn2').addClass('hide');
    }

});
```

**Updated** to use bootstrap class as per your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/180/)**

```
    if($('#mytable input:checkbox:checked').length > 1)
        $('#btn2').show();
    else
        $('#btn2').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    var val = 0;
var groupTrCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj={};
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(".span4").val() != "") {
            $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr' + val + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#mytr" + val);
            $tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" unchecked ></td>');
            $(".span4").each(function () {
                $tr.append("<td >" + $(this).val() + "</td>");
            });
            var arr={};
            name=($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
            email=($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());
            mobile=($tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
            arr['name']=name;arr['email']=email;arr['mobile']=mobile;
            obj[val]=arr;
            val++;
        } else {
            alert("please fill the form completely");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
        var creat_group = confirm("Do you want to creat a group??");
        if (creat_group) {
            console.log(obj);

            $tr.append("<td >" + groupTrCount + "</td>");

$("#groupsTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
    $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
    $tr.append("<td >Group:" + groupTrCount + "</td>"); // or you can use whatever name you want in place of "Group:"
    var userColumn = "<ul>";
    $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
      var count=0;
      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
         if(count == 1){
        userColumn+= "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>" ;
         }
         count++;
    });
});;
            userColumn+="<ul>";
            $tr.append("<td >" +userColumn+ "</td>");
        groupTrCount++;
        }        
    });
    $(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
        var rowCount = $('#mytable tr').length;
        if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 1 && rowcount > 6) {
        $('#btn2').removeClass('hide')
    }
    });
});
```

Updted Fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/184/

Comment: in this fiddle only group button visible when more than 5 users in the table